# Identify request to a Spring Boot Actuator endpoint in Filter

Tags: spring-boot, servlet-filters, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

How to identify that a request is for any of Spring Boot Actuator endpoints in a `javax.servlet.Filter`?

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    // Is req to any of Spring Actuator endpoint?

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }
```

My idea is to search for invoker class, or package (org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter), but I do not know exactly how.

Here is part of application log at start.

```
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/archaius || /archaius.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/features || /features.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/prometheus || /prometheus.json],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.export.prometheus.PrometheusScrapeMvcEndpoint.invoke()
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/env],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
EndpointHandlerMapping       : Mapped "{[/refresh || /refresh.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
```

Comment: You can just look for request uris corresponding to the actuator endpoints. It will be present in the HttpServletRequest object. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI()

Comment: The issue is Filter is not a spring thing . If you want to do something in the Spring World , you can think of spring security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spring Boot 2**:

It seems that situation in `Spring Boot 2` is different for every sub-version. Following code is mainly for inspiration and it must be tailored for the particular Spring Boot version:

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping;

public class ActuatorEndpointFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Inject
    private WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping mvcepMapping;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HandlerExecutionChain handlerChain = mvcepMapping.getHandler((HttpServletRequest) request);
            if (handlerChain != null) {
                Object handler = handlerChain.getHandler();
                // Following condition is enought in Spring Boot 2.1.1 and 2.1.2.
                if (handler.getClass().getName().startsWith(
                        "org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping")) {
                    // IT IS ACTUATOR ENDPOINT in Spring 2.1.1 and 2.1.2!!!!
                }

                // Following conditions are mandatory in Spring Boot <= 2.1.0.RELEASE
                if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) { 
                    Object bean = ((HandlerMethod) handler).getBean();
                    if (bean.getClass().getName().startsWith(
                            "org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping")) {
                        // IT IS ACTUATOR ENDPOINT in Spring 2.1.0!!!!
                    }
                }
           }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

*I suspect that first condition, `if (handlerChain != null)` i.e.: if `WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping` returns a handler, might be enough, at the moment, for any Spring Boot 2 version, but I did not investigated it further.*

Comment: How to handle this ``Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping' in your configuration.``

Answer (score 1):

You can change the actuator context path to /management, so that all requests are coming to `http://<host>:<port>/management/<here-come-your-endpoints>`

In Spring Boot 1.5.3 that we use it can be done easily by specifying the property:

```
management.context-path=/management
```

in **application.properties** file

This makes the actuator easy trackable and allows flexible configurations when it comes to what gets exposed by a gateway and what doesn't.

Comment: Mark, Thank you for effort. Your post does not answer the question. How to find out that an actuator endpoint was called in a filter.

Comment: I know that it doesn't answer but if you "separate" all the requests, then the check in filter becomes trivial : from the filter you can just access the request url path and analyze it, if it starts with /management - then its for actuator.