# How to know when prometheus server pulls metric from spring boot?

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

Is there a way to intercept calls to `actuator/prometheus` in the spring boot application?

I need to change the metric value once the pull request happens. This is what I have tried, but the request to the actuator wsn't filtered.

```java
@Component
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/actuator")
public class ActuatorFilter implements Filter {

  
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        chain.doFilter(request,response);
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HandlerExecutionChain handlerChain = null;
            try {
                HttpServletRequest request1 = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                request1.getRequestURI();
                // do something
                }

             catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        Filter.super.destroy();
    }
}
```

After following the discussion on Spring Github, I implemented this

```
@ManagementContextConfiguration
public class ActuatorFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<ActuatorFilter> registrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<ActuatorFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new ActuatorFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/actuator/prometheus");

        registrationBean.getFilter();
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify request to a Spring Boot Actuator endpoint in Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993631/identify-request-to-a-spring-boot-actuator-endpoint-in-filter)

Comment: no i does not, tried it but didnt work

Comment: in that case please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with any errors, configuration and trials you've made in the original question

Comment: My apologies, added sample code

Comment: please add any logs that were produced and configurations you've used with said code

Comment: I was able to add Filter after following the discussion https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16098

Comment: Filter worked after adding config, I have a follow up question, is there a way to use Main Application Component in Management Context

Comment: in that case answer the question with the full explained solution and search\open a different question for the follow up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the discussion here at [Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16098). I implemented a class with management context configuration annotation.

```
@ManagementContextConfiguration
public class ActuatorFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<ActuatorFilter> registrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<ActuatorFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new ActuatorFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/actuator/prometheus");

        registrationBean.getFilter();
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

My filter class looks like this

```
@Order(1)
public class ActuatorFilter implements Filter {
    
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        // Do something
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        // Do something
        }
```

Since my actuator runs on a different port. I have to use **@ManagementContextConfiguration** along with spring.factories file. The location for spring.factories is as follows:

> main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories

with the following content

> org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration = "path to the configuration class"